# ¿Cómo obtener un desplazamiento más suave ya sea con CSS u otro medio?

Tags: html, css

Quiero obtener un desplazamiento exactamente como el de esta página (más suave):
[Ejemplo de cómo quiero que sea mi desplazamiento](https://getwith.io/es/preguntas-para-programadores-front-end-pasar-la-entrevista-sin-experiencia/)

Ejemplo de un desplazamiento normal para que noten la comparación: [Ejemplo de desplazamiento NO suave](https://www.netflix.com/mx/)

Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo, no sé exactamente por donde comenzar (si fuese implementar scroll-behavior...). Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: Un comentario no relacionado a la pregunta pero a UX: Considera que el smooth scroll puede provocar scrolljacking y esto suele ser poco intuitivo y perjudicial https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/what-is-scroll-hijacking/ https://beamtic.com/scrolljacking-a-ux-problem https://codeless.co/scroll-hijacking/

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, me ayudan bastante.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Al fin y al cabo tuve que descargar el source de la web, e inspeccionando todos los archivos encontré el archivo que lograr hacer ese desplazamiento que deseo. Es algo complejo, por lo que estaré estudiándolo para entenderlo mejor. Y si alguien llega a necesitarlo aquí adjunto el código:

```
!(function () {
    var u,
        l,
        c,
        o = {
            frameRate: 150,
            animationTime: 400,
            stepSize: 100,
            pulseAlgorithm: !0,
            pulseScale: 4,
            pulseNormalize: 1,
            accelerationDelta: 50,
            accelerationMax: 3,
            keyboardSupport: !0,
            arrowScroll: 50,
            touchpadSupport: !1,
            fixedBackground: !0,
            excluded: "",
        },
        v = o,
        s = !1,
        d = !1,
        n = { x: 0, y: 0 },
        m = !1,
        f = document.documentElement,
        a = [],
        i = /^Mac/.test(navigator.platform),
        w = {
            left: 37,
            up: 38,
            right: 39,
            down: 40,
            spacebar: 32,
            pageup: 33,
            pagedown: 34,
            end: 35,
            home: 36,
        },
        h = { 37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1 };
    function p() {
        if (!m && document.body) {
            m = !0;
            var e = document.body,
                t = document.documentElement,
                o = window.innerHeight,
                n = e.scrollHeight;
            if (
                ((f = 0 <= document.compatMode.indexOf("CSS") ? t : e),
                    (u = e),
                    v.keyboardSupport && N("keydown", S),
                    top != self)
            )
                d = !0;
            else if (J && o < n && (e.offsetHeight <= o || t.offsetHeight <= o)) {
                var r,
                    a = document.createElement("div");
                (a.style.cssText =
                    "position:absolute; z-index:-10000; top:0; left:0; right:0; height:" +
                    f.scrollHeight +
                    "px"),
                    document.body.appendChild(a),
                    (c = function () {
                        r ||
                            (r = setTimeout(function () {
                                s ||
                                    ((a.style.height = "0"),
                                        (a.style.height = f.scrollHeight + "px"),
                                        (r = null));
                            }, 500));
                    }),
                    setTimeout(c, 10),
                    N("resize", c);
                if (
                    ((l = new P(c)).observe(e, {
                        attributes: !0,
                        childList: !0,
                        characterData: !1,
                    }),
                        f.offsetHeight <= o)
                ) {
                    var i = document.createElement("div");
                    (i.style.clear = "both"), e.appendChild(i);
                }
            }
            v.fixedBackground ||
                s ||
                ((e.style.backgroundAttachment = "scroll"),
                    (t.style.backgroundAttachment = "scroll"));
        }
    }
    var y = [],
        b = !1,
        r = Date.now();
    function g(m, f, w) {
        if (
            ((function (e, t) {
                (e = 0 < e ? 1 : -1),
                    (t = 0 < t ? 1 : -1),
                    (n.x === e && n.y === t) || ((n.x = e), (n.y = t), (y = []), (r = 0));
            })(f, w),
                1 != v.accelerationMax)
        ) {
            var e = Date.now() - r;
            if (e < v.accelerationDelta) {
                var t = (1 + 50 / e) / 2;
                1 < t && ((t = Math.min(t, v.accelerationMax)), (f *= t), (w *= t));
            }
            r = Date.now();
        }
        if (
            (y.push({
                x: f,
                y: w,
                lastX: f < 0 ? 0.99 : -0.99,
                lastY: w < 0 ? 0.99 : -0.99,
                start: Date.now(),
            }),
                !b)
        ) {
            var h = m === document.body,
                p = function (e) {
                    for (var t, o = Date.now(), n = 0, r = 0, a = 0; a < y.length; a++) {
                        var i = y[a],
                            l = o - i.start,
                            c = l >= v.animationTime,
                            u = c ? 1 : l / v.animationTime;
                        v.pulseAlgorithm && (u = V(u));
                        var s = (i.x * u - i.lastX) >> 0,
                            d = (i.y * u - i.lastY) >> 0;
                        (n += s),
                            (r += d),
                            (i.lastX += s),
                            (i.lastY += d),
                            c && (y.splice(a, 1), a--);
                    }
                    h
                        ? window.scrollBy(n, r)
                        : (n && (m.scrollLeft += n), r && (m.scrollTop += r)),
                        document.createEvent
                            ? (t = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")).initEvent(
                                "smoothScrollCustomEvent",
                                !0,
                                !0
                            )
                            : ((t = document.createEventObject()).eventType =
                                "smoothScrollCustomEvent"),
                        (t.eventName = "smoothScrollCustomEvent"),
                        document.createEvent
                            ? window.dispatchEvent(t)
                            : window.fireEvent("on" + t.eventType, t),
                        f || w || (y = []),
                        y.length ? j(p, m, 1e3 / v.frameRate + 1) : (b = !1);
                };
            j(p, m, 0), (b = !0);
        }
    }
    function e(e) {
        m || p();
        var t = e.target;
        if (e.defaultPrevented || e.ctrlKey) return !0;
        if (
            Y(u, "embed") ||
            (Y(t, "embed") && /\.pdf/i.test(t.src)) ||
            Y(u, "object") ||
            t.shadowRoot
        )
            return !0;
        var o = -e.wheelDeltaX || e.deltaX || 0,
            n = -e.wheelDeltaY || e.deltaY || 0;
        i &&
            (e.wheelDeltaX &&
                A(e.wheelDeltaX, 120) &&
                (o = (e.wheelDeltaX / Math.abs(e.wheelDeltaX)) * -120),
                e.wheelDeltaY &&
                A(e.wheelDeltaY, 120) &&
                (n = (e.wheelDeltaY / Math.abs(e.wheelDeltaY)) * -120)),
            o || n || (n = -e.wheelDelta || 0),
            1 === e.deltaMode && ((o *= 40), (n *= 40));
        var r = H(t);
        return r
            ? !(
                v.touchpadSupport ||
                !(function (e) {
                    if (!e) return;
                    a.length || (a = [e, e, e]);
                    return (
                        (e = Math.abs(e)),
                        a.push(e),
                        a.shift(),
                        clearTimeout(k),
                        (k = setTimeout(function () {
                            try {
                                localStorage.SS_deltaBuffer = a.join(",");
                            } catch (e) { }
                        }, 1e3)),
                        !B(120) && !B(100)
                    );
                })(n)
            ) ||
            (1.2 < Math.abs(o) && (o *= v.stepSize / 120),
                1.2 < Math.abs(n) && (n *= v.stepSize / 120),
                g(r, o, n),
                e.preventDefault(),
                void T())
            : !d ||
            !W ||
            (Object.defineProperty(e, "target", { value: window.frameElement }),
                parent.wheel(e));
    }
    function S(e) {
        var t = e.target,
            o =
                e.ctrlKey ||
                e.altKey ||
                e.metaKey ||
                (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode !== w.spacebar);
        document.body.contains(u) || (u = document.activeElement);
        var n = /^(button|submit|radio|checkbox|file|color|image)$/i;
        if (
            e.defaultPrevented ||
            /^(textarea|select|embed|object)$/i.test(t.nodeName) ||
            (Y(t, "input") && !n.test(t.type)) ||
            Y(u, "video") ||
            (function (e) {
                var t = e.target,
                    o = !1;
                if (-1 != document.URL.indexOf("www.youtube.com/watch"))
                    do {
                        if (
                            (o = t.classList && t.classList.contains("html5-video-controls"))
                        )
                            break;
                    } while ((t = t.parentNode));
                return o;
            })(e) ||
            t.isContentEditable ||
            o
        )
            return !0;
        if (
            (Y(t, "button") || (Y(t, "input") && n.test(t.type))) &&
            e.keyCode === w.spacebar
        )
            return !0;
        if (Y(t, "input") && "radio" == t.type && h[e.keyCode]) return !0;
        var r = 0,
            a = 0,
            i = H(u);
        if (!i) return !d || !W || parent.keydown(e);
        var l = i.clientHeight;
        switch ((i == document.body && (l = window.innerHeight), e.keyCode)) {
            case w.up:
                a = -v.arrowScroll;
                break;
            case w.down:
                a = v.arrowScroll;
                break;
            case w.spacebar:
                a = -(e.shiftKey ? 1 : -1) * l * 0.9;
                break;
            case w.pageup:
                a = 0.9 * -l;
                break;
            case w.pagedown:
                a = 0.9 * l;
                break;
            case w.home:
                a = -i.scrollTop;
                break;
            case w.end:
                var c = i.scrollHeight - i.scrollTop - l;
                a = 0 < c ? 10 + c : 0;
                break;
            case w.left:
                r = -v.arrowScroll;
                break;
            case w.right:
                r = v.arrowScroll;
                break;
            default:
                return !0;
        }
        g(i, r, a), e.preventDefault(), T();
    }
    function t(e) {
        u = e.target;
    }
    var x,
        E,
        k,
        D =
            ((x = 0),
                function (e) {
                    return e.uniqueID || (e.uniqueID = x++);
                }),
        M = {};
    function T() {
        clearTimeout(E),
            (E = setInterval(function () {
                M = {};
            }, 1e3));
    }
    function C(e, t) {
        for (var o = e.length; o--;) M[D(e[o])] = t;
        return t;
    }
    function H(e) {
        var t = [],
            o = document.body,
            n = f.scrollHeight;
        do {
            var r = M[D(e)];
            if (r) return C(t, r);
            if ((t.push(e), n === e.scrollHeight)) {
                var a = (L(f) && L(o)) || O(f);
                if ((d && z(f)) || (!d && a)) return C(t, R());
            } else if (z(e) && O(e)) return C(t, e);
        } while ((e = e.parentElement));
    }
    function z(e) {
        return e.clientHeight + 10 < e.scrollHeight;
    }
    function L(e) {
        return "hidden" !== getComputedStyle(e, "").getPropertyValue("overflow-y");
    }
    function O(e) {
        var t = getComputedStyle(e, "").getPropertyValue("overflow-y");
        return "scroll" === t || "auto" === t;
    }
    function N(e, t, o) {
        var n = o || !1;
        window.addEventListener(e, t, n);
    }
    function X(e, t, o) {
        var n = o || !1;
        window.removeEventListener(e, t, n);
    }
    function Y(e, t) {
        return (e.nodeName || "").toLowerCase() === t.toLowerCase();
    }
    if (window.localStorage && localStorage.SS_deltaBuffer)
        try {
            a = localStorage.SS_deltaBuffer.split(",");
        } catch (e) { }
    function A(e, t) {
        return Math.floor(e / t) == e / t;
    }
    function B(e) {
        return A(a[0], e) && A(a[1], e) && A(a[2], e);
    }
    var K,
        j =
            window.requestAnimationFrame ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
            function (e, t, o) {
                window.setTimeout(e, o || 1e3 / 60);
            },
        P =
            window.MutationObserver ||
            window.WebKitMutationObserver ||
            window.MozMutationObserver,
        R = function () {
            if (!K) {
                var e = document.createElement("div");
                (e.style.cssText = "height:10000px;width:1px;"),
                    document.body.appendChild(e);
                var t = document.body.scrollTop;
                document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                    window.scrollBy(0, 3),
                    (K =
                        document.body.scrollTop != t
                            ? document.body
                            : document.documentElement),
                    window.scrollBy(0, -3),
                    document.body.removeChild(e);
            }
            return K;
        };
    function q(e) {
        var t;
        return (
            ((e *= v.pulseScale) < 1
                ? e - (1 - Math.exp(-e))
                : ((e -= 1), (t = Math.exp(-1)) + (1 - Math.exp(-e)) * (1 - t))) *
            v.pulseNormalize
        );
    }
    function V(e) {
        return 1 <= e
            ? 1
            : e <= 0
                ? 0
                : (1 == v.pulseNormalize && (v.pulseNormalize /= q(1)), q(e));
    }
    var F,
        I = window.navigator.userAgent,
        _ = /Edge/.test(I),
        W = /chrome/i.test(I) && !_,
        $ = /safari/i.test(I) && !_,
        U = /mobile/i.test(I),
        G = /Windows NT 6.1/i.test(I) && /rv:11/i.test(I),
        J = $ && (/Version\/8/i.test(I) || /Version\/9/i.test(I)),
        Q = (W || $ || G) && !U;
    function Z(e) {
        for (var t in e) o.hasOwnProperty(t) && (v[t] = e[t]);
    }
    "onwheel" in document.createElement("div")
        ? (F = "wheel")
        : "onmousewheel" in document.createElement("div") && (F = "mousewheel"),
        F &&
        Q &&
        ((window.isSmoothScroll = !0),
            N(F, e, { passive: !1 }),
            N("mousedown", t),
            N("load", p)),
        (Z.destroy = function () {
            l && l.disconnect(),
                X(F, e, { passive: !1 }),
                X("mousedown", t),
                X("keydown", S),
                X("resize", c),
                X("load", p);
        }),
        window.SmoothScrollOptions && Z(window.SmoothScrollOptions),
        "function" == typeof define && define.amd
            ? define(function () {
                return Z;
            })
            : "object" == typeof exports
                ? (module.exports = Z)
                : (window.SmoothScroll = Z);
})();
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: Efectivamente, así es, como mencioné está bajo estudio y análisis, para poder dar un feedback del mismo, y más sepan comprenderlo.

Answer (score 1):

Te comparto una muy buena opción, para no andar buscando vueltas y no modificar tantas cosas.

Esta sujerencia usa la libreria jQuery, y el plugin es nicescroll. Ver [demo](https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/demo/).

Nicescroll no es solamente scroll suave, sino tambien tiene un diseño de las barra laterales.

Primero es necesario tener jQuery, luego nicescroll.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.7.6/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
```

Luego definir algunos ajustes pequeño para la barra lateral.

```js
$("html").niceScroll({ // estilo de la barra
cursorwidth: 5,
cursoropacitymin: 0.5,
cursorcolor:'red',
cursorborder:'none',
cursorborderradius: 5,
autohidemode: 'leave'
});
```

```css
section {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}

p {
    margin: 20px 0;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<section>

<h1>Hermoso y suave scroll de página</h1>

    <p><b><a href="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.nicescroll" target="_blank">Pagina</a></b> <b><a href="https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll" target="_blank">Github</a></b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, facilis mollitia sunt ad soluta doloribus, voluptatum, ullam reprehenderit maxime perferendis natus aliquid architecto deserunt repudiandae quas voluptas facere ducimus officia animi? Fuga veritatis, optio consequatur saepe animi architecto deserunt quibusdam labore eaque ab at aperiam maiores voluptatum harum repellendus veniam corrupti est explicabo mollitia rem qui molestias! Vero, repudiandae cumque debitis laboriosam consequatur nobis quo perferendis itaque minus voluptatem voluptas optio at molestiae magni placeat dolores eligendi dicta facere inventore fuga beatae sint? Consequuntur repellendus, fugiat ut eos illo officiis nesciunt sapiente excepturi quod dolor ab. Atque quae sapiente perferendis?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, facilis mollitia sunt ad soluta doloribus, voluptatum, ullam reprehenderit maxime perferendis natus aliquid architecto deserunt repudiandae quas voluptas facere ducimus officia animi? Fuga veritatis, optio consequatur saepe animi architecto deserunt quibusdam labore eaque ab at aperiam maiores voluptatum harum repellendus veniam corrupti est explicabo mollitia rem qui molestias! Vero, repudiandae cumque debitis laboriosam consequatur nobis quo perferendis itaque minus voluptatem voluptas optio at molestiae magni placeat dolores eligendi dicta facere inventore fuga beatae sint? Consequuntur repellendus, fugiat ut eos illo officiis nesciunt sapiente excepturi quod dolor ab. Atque quae sapiente perferendis?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, facilis mollitia sunt ad soluta doloribus, voluptatum, ullam reprehenderit maxime perferendis natus aliquid architecto deserunt repudiandae quas voluptas facere ducimus officia animi? Fuga veritatis, optio consequatur saepe animi architecto deserunt quibusdam labore eaque ab at aperiam maiores voluptatum harum repellendus veniam corrupti est explicabo mollitia rem qui molestias! Vero, repudiandae cumque debitis laboriosam consequatur nobis quo perferendis itaque minus voluptatem voluptas optio at molestiae magni placeat dolores eligendi dicta facere inventore fuga beatae sint? Consequuntur repellendus, fugiat ut eos illo officiis nesciunt sapiente excepturi quod dolor ab. Atque quae sapiente perferendis?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, facilis mollitia sunt ad soluta doloribus, voluptatum, ullam reprehenderit maxime perferendis natus aliquid architecto deserunt repudiandae quas voluptas facere ducimus officia animi? Fuga veritatis, optio consequatur saepe animi architecto deserunt quibusdam labore eaque ab at aperiam maiores voluptatum harum repellendus veniam corrupti est explicabo mollitia rem qui molestias! Vero, repudiandae cumque debitis laboriosam consequatur nobis quo perferendis itaque minus voluptatem voluptas optio at molestiae magni placeat dolores eligendi dicta facere inventore fuga beatae sint? Consequuntur repellendus, fugiat ut eos illo officiis nesciunt sapiente excepturi quod dolor ab. Atque quae sapiente perferendis?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, facilis mollitia sunt ad soluta doloribus, voluptatum, ullam reprehenderit maxime perferendis natus aliquid architecto deserunt repudiandae quas voluptas facere ducimus officia animi? Fuga veritatis, optio consequatur saepe animi architecto deserunt quibusdam labore eaque ab at aperiam maiores voluptatum harum repellendus veniam corrupti est explicabo mollitia rem qui molestias! Vero, repudiandae cumque debitis laboriosam consequatur nobis quo perferendis itaque minus voluptatem voluptas optio at molestiae magni placeat dolores eligendi dicta facere inventore fuga beatae sint? Consequuntur repellendus, fugiat ut eos illo officiis nesciunt sapiente excepturi quod dolor ab. Atque quae sapiente perferendis?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, facilis mollitia sunt ad soluta doloribus, voluptatum, ullam reprehenderit maxime perferendis natus aliquid architecto deserunt repudiandae quas voluptas facere ducimus officia animi? Fuga veritatis, optio consequatur saepe animi architecto deserunt quibusdam labore eaque ab at aperiam maiores voluptatum harum repellendus veniam corrupti est explicabo mollitia rem qui molestias! Vero, repudiandae cumque debitis laboriosam consequatur nobis quo perferendis itaque minus voluptatem voluptas optio at molestiae magni placeat dolores eligendi dicta facere inventore fuga beatae sint? Consequuntur repellendus, fugiat ut eos illo officiis nesciunt sapiente excepturi quod dolor ab. Atque quae sapiente perferendis?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, facilis mollitia sunt ad soluta doloribus, voluptatum, ullam reprehenderit maxime perferendis natus aliquid architecto deserunt repudiandae quas voluptas facere ducimus officia animi? Fuga veritatis, optio consequatur saepe animi architecto deserunt quibusdam labore eaque ab at aperiam maiores voluptatum harum repellendus veniam corrupti est explicabo mollitia rem qui molestias! Vero, repudiandae cumque debitis laboriosam consequatur nobis quo perferendis itaque minus voluptatem voluptas optio at molestiae magni placeat dolores eligendi dicta facere inventore fuga beatae sint? Consequuntur repellendus, fugiat ut eos illo officiis nesciunt sapiente excepturi quod dolor ab. Atque quae sapiente perferendis?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, facilis mollitia sunt ad soluta doloribus, voluptatum, ullam reprehenderit maxime perferendis natus aliquid architecto deserunt repudiandae quas voluptas facere ducimus officia animi? Fuga veritatis, optio consequatur saepe animi architecto deserunt quibusdam labore eaque ab at aperiam maiores voluptatum harum repellendus veniam corrupti est explicabo mollitia rem qui molestias! Vero, repudiandae cumque debitis laboriosam consequatur nobis quo perferendis itaque minus voluptatem voluptas optio at molestiae magni placeat dolores eligendi dicta facere inventore fuga beatae sint? Consequuntur repellendus, fugiat ut eos illo officiis nesciunt sapiente excepturi quod dolor ab. Atque quae sapiente perferendis?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, facilis mollitia sunt ad soluta doloribus, voluptatum, ullam reprehenderit maxime perferendis natus aliquid architecto deserunt repudiandae quas voluptas facere ducimus officia animi? Fuga veritatis, optio consequatur saepe animi architecto deserunt quibusdam labore eaque ab at aperiam maiores voluptatum harum repellendus veniam corrupti est explicabo mollitia rem qui molestias! Vero, repudiandae cumque debitis laboriosam consequatur nobis quo perferendis itaque minus voluptatem voluptas optio at molestiae magni placeat dolores eligendi dicta facere inventore fuga beatae sint? Consequuntur repellendus, fugiat ut eos illo officiis nesciunt sapiente excepturi quod dolor ab. Atque quae sapiente perferendis?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, facilis mollitia sunt ad soluta doloribus, voluptatum, ullam reprehenderit maxime perferendis natus aliquid architecto deserunt repudiandae quas voluptas facere ducimus officia animi? Fuga veritatis, optio consequatur saepe animi architecto deserunt quibusdam labore eaque ab at aperiam maiores voluptatum harum repellendus veniam corrupti est explicabo mollitia rem qui molestias! Vero, repudiandae cumque debitis laboriosam consequatur nobis quo perferendis itaque minus voluptatem voluptas optio at molestiae magni placeat dolores eligendi dicta facere inventore fuga beatae sint? Consequuntur repellendus, fugiat ut eos illo officiis nesciunt sapiente excepturi quod dolor ab. Atque quae sapiente perferendis?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, facilis mollitia sunt ad soluta doloribus, voluptatum, ullam reprehenderit maxime perferendis natus aliquid architecto deserunt repudiandae quas voluptas facere ducimus officia animi? Fuga veritatis, optio consequatur saepe animi architecto deserunt quibusdam labore eaque ab at aperiam maiores voluptatum harum repellendus veniam corrupti est explicabo mollitia rem qui molestias! Vero, repudiandae cumque debitis laboriosam consequatur nobis quo perferendis itaque minus voluptatem voluptas optio at molestiae magni placeat dolores eligendi dicta facere inventore fuga beatae sint? Consequuntur repellendus, fugiat ut eos illo officiis nesciunt sapiente excepturi quod dolor ab. Atque quae sapiente perferendis?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, facilis mollitia sunt ad soluta doloribus, voluptatum, ullam reprehenderit maxime perferendis natus aliquid architecto deserunt repudiandae quas voluptas facere ducimus officia animi? Fuga veritatis, optio consequatur saepe animi architecto deserunt quibusdam labore eaque ab at aperiam maiores voluptatum harum repellendus veniam corrupti est explicabo mollitia rem qui molestias! Vero, repudiandae cumque debitis laboriosam consequatur nobis quo perferendis itaque minus voluptatem voluptas optio at molestiae magni placeat dolores eligendi dicta facere inventore fuga beatae sint? Consequuntur repellendus, fugiat ut eos illo officiis nesciunt sapiente excepturi quod dolor ab. Atque quae sapiente perferendis?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, facilis mollitia sunt ad soluta doloribus, voluptatum, ullam reprehenderit maxime perferendis natus aliquid architecto deserunt repudiandae quas voluptas facere ducimus officia animi? Fuga veritatis, optio consequatur saepe animi architecto deserunt quibusdam labore eaque ab at aperiam maiores voluptatum harum repellendus veniam corrupti est explicabo mollitia rem qui molestias! Vero, repudiandae cumque debitis laboriosam consequatur nobis quo perferendis itaque minus voluptatem voluptas optio at molestiae magni placeat dolores eligendi dicta facere inventore fuga beatae sint? Consequuntur repellendus, fugiat ut eos illo officiis nesciunt sapiente excepturi quod dolor ab. Atque quae sapiente perferendis?</p>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.7.6/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, realmente sí es una buena opción, y sobre todo más entendible. Te agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 0):

En CSS existe una propiedad llamada scroll-behavior, aplicandolo al elemento html se aplica a toda la pagina.

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: Lo tengo agregado, pero no sé si se tiene que implementar más cosas, porque el desplazamiento sigue igual...

Comment: En chrome se puede habilitar el flag, navegando a:  chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling